# How to disable Music Lens

Tags: lenses

I'm trying to use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> for the magnifier.  However, when I hit the keyboard sequence it activates Music Lens instead.

I don't have a need for for the Music Lens, and would like to disable  it so that it doesn't interfere with the Magnifier key assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove unity music lens, it can't be disabled.

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-music
```